# Pygame: Couldn't open file. Same directory

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

I loaded 150 .tif images to a glob module and am currently unable to load them. I'm very new to programming so I imagine it's a dumb mistake I'm missing but I cant seem to figure it out.

The is the code:

```
import pygame, glob

types= ('*.tif')

artfile_names= []

for files in types:
    artfile_names.extend(glob.glob(files))

print(artfile_names)

for artworks in artfile_names:
    pygame.image.load(str(artfile_names))
```

Thank you for any help!

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake is that your `types` variable is just a string (wrapping it in parentheses has no effect), so you iterate over the letters in the string and call `artfile_names.extend(glob.glob(files))` for each letter.

The comma makes the tuple (except for the empty tuple):

```
types = '*.tif',  # This gives you a tuple with the length 1.

types = '*.tif', '*.png'  # This is a tuple with two elements.
```

---

In the second part of your code, you need to iterate over the `artfile_names`, call `pygame.image.load(artwork)` to load the image from your hard disk and append the resulting [surface](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) to a list:

```
images = []

for artwork in artfile_names:
    images.append(pygame.image.load(artwork).convert())
```

Call the `.convert()` method (or `.convert_alpha()` for images with transparency) to improve the blit performance.

Comment: BTW, that code only loads the images, but it doesn't display anything. Do you read or watch a pygame tutorial? You need a while loop in which you  use the `.blit` method of your pygame display surface to blit the images.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for the clarification :)

Comment: No problem. [Program Arcade Games](http://programarcadegames.com/index.php?chapter=introduction_to_graphics&lang=en#section_5) is a good book about Python and pygame if you need a tutorial.